# Nextjs x Framer Motion inertial scrolling with page transition

Tags: next.js, smooth-scrolling, framer-motion, page-transition

I've been working on an inertial scrolling implementation within Nextjs using Framer Motion but running into a bit of trouble when animation page transitions using animate presence. I'm hooking into the page scroll progress via `useScroll` and animating the Y transform with spring physics. The issue, however, is when resetting the window scroll position when navigating between pages. After the component has unmounted, I call `window.scrollTo(0,0)` via the `AnimatePresence` `onExitComplete` callback, but because I'm transforming the page position via spring physics, the scroll reset doesn't complete immediately. So when new pages are mounted, the page transform to reset the scroll is still running.

Additionally, I've included `scroll={false}` in my Next `Link` components to prevent the default scroll to top functionality so I can handle this manually via the `AnimatePresence` component as mentioned above. But this doesn't seem to be working.

There's a bit of code involved so I created a minimal reproduction repo [here](https://github.com/hansenconnor/nextjs-framer-motion-smooth-scroll-transition).

I also notice that passing `scrollY` to the y property of the variant object prevents the unwanted scrolling behavior on page transition. But passing something like `scrollY - 128` breaks the behavior:

```
 const variants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: 64 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
    exit: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: scrollY },
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y value in exit variant wasn't being updated to match latest scrollY value. Solution:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return scrollY.onChange((latest) => {
      variants.exit.y = -scrollY.current - 128;
    });
  });
```